# scrolling KTextEdit to start

Tags: linux, qt, kdelibs

I have a KTextEdit, filled with some text.

When I put lots of text, the KTextEdit will be scrolled automatically to the end (obviously).

My question is: how can I scroll to the start (viz to the first line of the KTextEdit) ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you use

```
QTextCursor cursor = edit->textCursor();
cursor.setPosition(0);
edit->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

Not tested, but looks fine. Found another, shorter way:

```
edit->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Start);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way i can think of is:

```
KTextEdit *kte;
...
kte->append("some huge text");
kte->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(0);
```